# Workers en una aplicación Electron + React.js

Tags: reactjs, electron

Tengo una duda, quiero implementar workers en una aplicación Electron + React.js, para realizar una sincronización de millones de datos.

La solución que encontre fue workers.

Pero no encuentro algún ejemplo de como usarlo, o que modules de node, puedo utilizar.

Segui el manual del link siguiente:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/Performance/Usando_web_workers

Pero cuando creo el worker, como en el ejemplo me da el siguiente error:

error not found 404 localhost:8080/spc/worker.js

Necesito ayuda.. con todo lo que puedan.